# Where is the GUI config for Server Admin held?

Tags: domain-name-system, osx-snow-leopard, mac-osx-server

I'm currently trying to migrate my DNS server from one Mac OS X Server to another. What I've done is rsync all the data in the `/var/named` folder. However Server Admin is not recognizing my zones, what file controls what server admin sees for DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the directory I needed to copy over was `/etc/dns`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably `/etc/named.conf`.

You should also copy over any other files referenced therein.